# How can i get the horizontal scroll with responsive and scrollcollapse?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a datatable that has horizontal scrolling. The create table statement I am using here as follows:
"scrollY": "260px"
if i am using with responsive and scrollcollapse command the scrollY type is not working.
When I remove the scrollY the page is working properly. But i need scrollY property.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Try "scrollY":"auto".

Scroll adjunts automatic to windows in responsive dev.

Comment: thanks for ur reply... but "auto" property is not page responsive for my pagination screen. so i need a scrollY with pixel size only like "260px".

Comment: Other option is recover datatable with div that have 260px and put datatable scrollY auto.